# Есть ли возможность с помощью команды в cmd получить информацию, кем был сохранен файл .xlsx?

Tags: debian, командная-строка, xlsx

Необходимо определить имя пользователя из метаданных .xlsx файла,того кто последний сохранил файл.
Интересуют команды в операционных системах WIndows11/Linux/Debian12